# Help needed on writing extension for Google Chrome/Mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

I would like to create a extension for Google Chrome/Mozilla for the following requirement.
If I search for any text in a web page, If text is found then automatically background colour has to be added to that text.Basically it will be done by browser. But multiple searches are possible. So I need to make all the searched and found texts highlighted. I know very basics of writing extensions for Google chrome( I have learnt through http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html ) . I have good knowledge on JavaScript. I don't have any basic idea to achieve the solution for my requirement. Please someone guide me on how to proceed further.

Comment: I need basic guidelines on how to write basic functionalities. And very thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't have an answer for Google Chrome, making a Firefox addon is simple.

Take a look at the [addon SDK and addon builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) and the [documentation for it](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/). [The first tutorial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/implementing-simple-addon.html) outlines the setups you will need to take and it should help get you started. Also, ou will probably need the [page-mod library](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html).